# Azure Data Factory - Azure Data Lake Gen1 access

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake

A file is being added by the Logic Apps to the Data Factory V2
I have a Data Factory that access 'data lake gen 1' to process the file. I receive the following error, when I try to debug the data factory after file is added.

```
 "ErrorCode=FileForbidden,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Failed to read a 'AzureDataLakeStore' file. File path: 'Stem/Benchmark/DB_0_Measures_1_05052020 - Copy - Copy - rounded, date changed - Copy (3).csv'.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary,''Type=System.Net.WebException,Message=The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.,Source=System,'",
```

When I "Apply to children"  after next load permission, error is gone.
Tried so far:
- Assigned permission in Data Lake for the Data Factory and it`s children.

- Assigned permission in Data Lake Folder for the Data Factory and it's children.
- Added data factory as a contributor to data lake.
- Added data factory as an owner to data lake.
- Allowed "all Azure services to access this Data Lake Storage Gen1 account".

After all tries, still need manually to "apply permission to children" for each file added.

Is there anyway to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Can reproduce your error:

[image]

This is how I resolve:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

And my account is the owner of the data lake gen1. The datafactory is the contributor of the data lake gen1.

[image]

Comment: Hi Bowman. This does not work. After adding new file, still have 403 error.

Answer (score 0):

you need to give Read + Execute Access on parent folders and then do what @Bowman Zhu mentioned above.